# Unable to get click event listener to work on svg element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an `svg` text element. I implemented an `onclick` event on the text so that every time I click on the text it would grow bigger. Somehow its not working.

CSS:

```
 <style>
            html,
            body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
            }

            .container {
                background-color: yellow;
                z-index: 7;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                opacity: .5;
            }

            .textBox {
                background-color: blue;
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 10px;
                left: 0px;
                right: 0px;
            }

            #text1 {
                animation-name: diamondOrigin;
                animation-duration: 8s;
                animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            }

            @keyframes diamondOrigin {
                from {
                    transform: scale(1);
                }

                to {
                    transform: scale(300);
                }
            }
 </style>
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="textBox">
        <p>fljsfa</p>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <svg height="100%" width="100%">    
              <text id="text1" onclick="grow()" x="0" y="10" fill="red">I love SVG</text>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
 <script>
       function grow() {
                    var changeText = document.getElementById("text1");
                    var compStyles = window.getComputedStyle(changeText);
                    changeText.textContent = 'Works?';
                }
        grow();
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were applying the css animation directly to the element, and the click function was working correctly, as the text was changing to "Works",

Here's the solution

```js
function grow(e) {
   e.classList.add('text1');
}
```

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index: 7;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: .5;
}

.textBox {
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

.text1 {
    animation-name: diamondOrigin;
    animation-duration: 8s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes diamondOrigin {
    from {
        transform: scale(1);
    }

    to {
        transform: scale(300);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="textBox">
    <p>fljsfa</p>
</div>
    
<div class="container">
    <svg height="100%" width="100%">
     <text id="text1" onclick="grow(this)" x="0" y="10" fill="red">I love SVG</text> 
  </svg>
</container>
```